# How to center a field within a column of a Visualforce datatable

Tags: visualforce, datatable

I am attempting to center the contents of an outputfield which I am placing into a datatable's column. I can't find an attribute for the datatable which can do this. The closest I can find is an attribute which will center the datatable itself, but I don't want that.

Here is an example of the code :

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!Vendor_Product_Review__c}" var="pitem" border="4"  align="left" cellpadding="10" rowClasses="rowWithBorder"> 


                      <apex:column headerValue="" >
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Credit   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Liquidity   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Transaction   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Foreign Exchange   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Interest Rate   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Reputation   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Operational   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Price   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Compliance   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Strategic   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Financial  </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputLabel >Other   </apex:outputLabel><br></br>
                             </apex:column>

                             <apex:column headerValue="Probability" >
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.CreditRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.LiquidityRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.TransactionRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.ForeignExchangeRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.InterestRateRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.ReputationRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.OperationalRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.PriceRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.ComplianceRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.StrategicRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.FinancialRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                                 <apex:outputfield value="{!pitem.OtherRiskProbability__c}"/><br></br>
                             </apex:column>
```

I would like the outputlabels to be centered within their column as well.

Anybody got an idea on this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use css in vf page

```
<style>
tbody{text-align:center}
</style>
```

for only a single table

provide any class to table

```
<style>
.tableClass tbody{text-align:center}
</style>


<apex:dataTable styleClass="tableClass">
<apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: Ratan - one question : I just noticed that it is also centering the title of all of the sections throughout the whole page as well. I put that coding under the pageblockstation with the datatable in it. I don't understand this because I put the style="tbody" within the attributes of the datatable. I even putting the style="tbody" within only a specific columns attributes and that still caused the sections titles throoughout the page to center as well. What can I do about this ?

Comment: for specific pageblocktable or datatable just provide any class name and use in style .className  tbody{text-align:center}

Comment: I'm confused what should be the "class name" in this case. I put an id="thistable" within the datatable's attributes and then tried tbody.thistable{text-align:center} and then just used style="tbody" within the datatable. But that didn't work. Can you tell me how that should be done ? Thank you.

Comment: updated my code above plz check.

Comment: an alternative is to use the apex:dataTable `columnClasses` attribute to identify a class referenced by CSS - allows for distinct styling for column 1 vs 2.  In general VF components provide ways to style without having to know the underlying HTML.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you so much @Ratan ; I truly appreciate this.

Comment: Thank you also @crop1645 - again, very much appreciated.